# Delete row of panda dataframe iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, eval, bin

I know there are better ways to do that, but I'm interating over a pandas dataframe using `iterrows` to calculate a binned average and to delete rows at each iteration. I'm taking the number of rows I'm deleting from the number of data inside a bin. I'm doing this, instead of creating a constant number of bins at once, and then calculate the binned average, because I need to make sure that the bins are not overlapping. I did that before and I had this problem.
The part of the code below is what I'm using right now. It works for the first iteration, but after that, I get an error saying that `eval()`, cannot evaluate `df_name`: `eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object`

```
  for df_name in alldfs:        
      for row,index in eval(df_name).iterrows():   
           ranges=np.arange(eval(df_name).A.min()-0.1 , eval(df_name).A.max() + 0.1, 0.1)  
           groups = eval(df_name).groupby(pd.cut(eval(df_name).mass, ranges,include_lowest=True))
           df_bin=pd.DataFrame(groups.mean())
           df_bin['binned']=eval(df_name).groupby(pd.cut(eval(df_name).mass, ranges, include_lowest=True)).size()
           number_bin=np.array(df_bin['binned'])[0]   
           df_name=eval(df_name).drop(eval(df_name).index[0:number_bin])
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of `eval()` must be a string.

Try to corret to this form:

```
eval('df_name')
```

Notice that I've used the dataframe's name as a string, to eval interpret the string and read it as python code.

Comment: Thanks. It works well for the first iteration.  Anyways, I tried your suggestion and got `'str' object has no attribute 'A'`